# How do you change the default collation of MySql for rake db:create:all in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, rake

In my rails app I am running rake db:create:all in order to create the databases and I am prompted that the collations do not match. 
Is there a way to change the default MySQL collation? If not what is the best way around this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are the collation options specified in your MySQL configuration file (normally named my.cnf). It should look something like this (in the `[mysqld]` section):

```
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

More info:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-server.html
- http://macboypro.com/blog/2009/07/31/mysql-5-1-riding-on-utf8-collation-client-and-server-tutorial/
- http://mysql2.mirrors-r-us.net/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-connection.html